# Venga da me - meaning of "da"

Tags: prepositions

I know that "da" may mean to/at, when someone is talking about "one's place/home" or "one's work place", as "chez" in French. Examples:

> Devo portare il piccolo Luigi dal pediatra. (I must take the little
>   Luigi to the pediatrician)
>
> È da sua madre. (He is at his mother's)

However, I have just heard "Venga da me". I thought it would mean "Come to my place", but it was translated as "Come to me". Can it mean both? Is "venga a me" not usual?

Comment: _Venga a me_ sounds like something just a god or a king would say. Why do you find _venga da me_ different from _porto Luigi dal pediatra_? It's the same usage of _da_ to denote a destination (_moto a luogo_ in Italian), when the destination is a person; see item 2 [here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/da/).

Comment: Because "da" is not used for destinations in general (eg vieni al negozio, vieni in Germania, vieni nella mia stanza), only specific contexts such as the ones I mentioned beforehand. "To come to someone" seems to be one of these contexts, but I needed a confirmation. Thanks for providing it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Venga a me* would be theoretically correct, but it nowadays sounds hopelessly old-fashioned. A famous passage in [the gospel of Mark](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+10%3A14&version=KJV) has Jesus say “Suffer the little children to come unto me” (KJV; [*Sinite parvulos venire ad me*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sinite-parvulos-venire-ad-me/) in Latin), and it is usually phrased in Italian as *Lasciate che i bambini* [or *fanciulli*] *vengano a me*. But in modern everyday Italian you'd say something like *Lasciali venire da me*.

Indeed, among many other uses, *da* can denote a destination (*moto a luogo* in Italian), when the destination is a person, as in both the paediatrician and the *Venga da me* examples; see item 2 [here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/da/).

Comment: Consider also for example "Dove ci troviamo stasera? - Da me."

Comment: Making it clear to others: "da me" in the last example means "at the place/home of" ("da me" = "at my place"), unlike "da me" in my question, which means "to me".