"Da" used as "to"
Consider the following sentence:

I passeggeri tornano a casa dalle loro famiglie.

It seems a bit awkward if the sentence means:

The passengers are returning home from their families

Rather than:

The passengers are returning home to their families.

If latter is infact the correct translation, then "da" is used as "to" rather than its usual "from" usage, which I haven't seen before anywhere. What is going on here?

Related question: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/10877/.

Does this answer your question? correre [a] oppure [da]?

Da has many more uses than just “from”. Have a look here: https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/da/ In particular, your question is about this use: “il moto a luogo (solo con nomi o pronomi di persona): verrò oggi stesso da te; devo andare dal sarto; scendo dal tabaccaio”. Anyhow, see also the links in the other comments.

As stated in the book Grammatica e pratica della lingua italiana per studenti stranieri by Federica Colombo, one of the usages of preposition da is to express

un complemento di stato in luogo o moto a luogo, quando il luogo è indicato dal nome di una persona, da un pronome o dai nomi di professione come panettiere, fruttivendolo, ecc.:

Sono stato da Giovanna.
Vengo da te sabato sera.
Passo dal panettiere e poi vengo a casa.


That is, preposition da can be used to express a complement of stay at a place or of movement to a place when the place is indicated by the name of a person, a pronoun or the name of a profession such as panettiere, fruttivendolo, etc., as you can see in the examples above.
This is the case of your sentence, that may be translated as:

The passengers are returning home to their families place.

